# Large table delete in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, delete

I want to delete a table with 10,000,000 records. Due to some restrictions I can't do truncate on that table (I don't have the DROP privilege), I can think of two options:

1. DELETE QUICK
2. To set some table level logging off so that mysql doesn't put data
   in rollback segments and that could make it faster as it happens
   in oracle.

Please throw some light on it while keeping in mind that **I can't use TRUNCATE.**

Comment: Are there foreign key constraints, referencing the table? Perhaps you can DROP and (re)CREATE.

Comment: I can't drop the table, in that case i would have used TRUNCATE which does the same thing internally, but unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: Why can't you do that?

Comment: because i dont have drop privilege, i have insert update delete privileges only..

Comment: What is the engine of table ?

Comment: Hi Abdul i have tables in InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have privileges to DROP table you should DELETE in chunks.

Use MySQL Limit clause to delete in chunks.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 10000;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of chunk delete but i am more looking towards option like QUICK DELETE or to set logging off for that particular session. When i say logging i mean to say rollback logging.